# Bash scripting test that a datetime is in the past?

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

I'm writing a bash shell script one of whose arguments is a datetime. What's the best way to check if that date is in the past (or a certain amount of time in the past (e.g. “this was at least 3 days ago?”)).

bash v4, Ubuntu Linux 18.04+, standard FLOSS tools from `apt-get`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use GNU `date` (the implementation found on Ubuntu)'s ability to parse natural (English) language date/time specifications (and more) with its `-d` extension. The `+%s` format converts the date to seconds since the epoch which you can easily compare.

```
#!/bin/bash
date='2020-08-12T16:00:10'
epoch=$(date -d "$date" +%s)
if [ "$epoch" -lt "$(date -d '3 days ago' +%s)" ] ; then
    echo At least 3 days ago
else
    echo Too recent
fi
```